# -[__NSCFDictionary JSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, json

I'm about to build an application that support the Facebook share button using the open source library provided by github Facebook iOS SDK.

My problem is that when I press the button the application crashes, and I get this error:

```
2012-03-23 19:46:25.820 iLoctest[5557:15803] -[__NSCFDictionary JSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80c7a60
2012-03-23 19:46:25.826 iLoctest[5557:15803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary JSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80c7a60'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x12fd022 0x16e6cd6 0x12fecbd 0x1263ed0 0x1263cb2 0x477b 0x12fee99 0x33914e 0x3390e6 0x3dfade 0x3dffa7 0x3df266 0x35e3c0 0x35e5e6 0x344dc4 0x338634 0x1e2fef5 0x12d1195 0x1235ff2 0x12348da 0x1233d84 0x1233c9b 0x1e2e7d8 0x1e2e88a 0x336626 0x2acd 0x2a35 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

this my code :

```
- (IBAction)fBookButton:(id)sender {
NSMutableArray * locArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: countryText.text,townText.text,streetText.text,zipText.text, nil];

// Attachments
NSMutableDictionary* attach = [NSMutableDictionary  dictionary];
[attach setObject:@"iLoc" forKey:@"info"];

// Parameters

NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:facebookAPIKey forKey:@"API_Key"];
[params setObject:locArray forKey:@"locArray"];
[params setObject:[attach JSONRepresentation] forKey:@"attach"];


}
```

I'm using Xcode 4.3 with iOS 5.1.

If you have a tutorial or book on how to do the same with xcode 4.x, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you including the [JSON framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)? The `JSONRepresentation` method you're calling on the `NSMutableDictionary` instance isn't included in a new Xcode project, you need to download the source and include it in your project.